# How to match the last occurrence of a pattern on a single line string

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I am using this command line to get a particular line from an html file which contains various other tags, links etc.:

```
cat index.html | grep -m1 -oE '<a href="(.*?)" rel="sample"[\S\s]*.*</dd>'
```

It outputs the line which I want:

```
<a href="http://example.com/something/one/" rel="sample" >Foo</a> <a href="http://example.com/something/two/" rel="sample" >Bar</a></dd>
```

But I want to capture only `something/two` (the path of **the last** URL) considering that:

- the URLs are not known beforehand (it's a script processing multiple html files)
- the line can sometimes contain only 1 URL, e.g.

  ```
  <a href="http://example.com/something/one/" rel="sample" >Foo</a></dd>
  ```

  in which case I would want to get only `something/one` as in this case it is **the last** one.

How can I do that?

Comment: what if some `a` tag is breaked with newline so it occurs on two consecutive lines simultaneously?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest doesn't `[\S\s]*` cover that?

Comment: no, I suppose, he wants to define how many URLs are on a single line. If there are multiple urls - capture query strings, if a line contain only one url - capture only the last section of query string i.e.`/one/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use perl, then capturing within a regex makes this a lot easier.

```
 perl -ne 'm(.*<a href="[^:]+://[^/]*/(.*?)" rel="sample".*</dd>) and print "$1\n";'
```

The regex is basically the same as would also work with grep.  I've used `m()` instead of `//` to avoid escaping the `/` inside the regex.

The initial `.*` will greedily capture everything at the beginning of the line.  If you have multiple links on a line, it will capture all but the last.  This works with grep too, but it causes grep `-o` to output the beginning of the line, since this now matches the regex.

This doesn't matter with the capturing parenthesis, as only the part inside the `(.*?)` is captured and printed.

It would be used the same way as grep.

```
cat index.html | perl -ne 'm(.*<a href="[^:]+://[^/]*/(.*?)" rel="sample".*</dd>) and print "$1\n";'

or

perl -ne 'm(.*<a href="[^:]+://[^/]*/(.*?)" rel="sample".*</dd>) and print "$1\n";' index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
| grep -o 'href="[^"]*' | tail -n1
```

The first part only extracts the `href`s, the second part keeps only the last line.

If you want to extract only the path, you can use `cut` with delimiter set to `/` and extract everything starting from the fourth column:

```
| grep -o 'href="[^"]*' | tail -n1 | cut -f4- -d/
```

because

```
href="http://example.com/something/two/
1          23            4         5
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, GNU `grep`'s `-P` option enables a concise solution:

```
$ grep -oP '.*<a href="http://.+?/\K[^"]+(?=/"\s*rel="sample".*</dd>$)' index.html
something/two
```

`-o` only outputs the *matching part(s)* of each line that matches.

`-P` activates support for [PRCEs (Perl-compatible Regular Expressions)](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcre.html), which supports advanced regex constructs such as non-greedy matching (`*?`), dropping everything matched so far (`\K`), and look-ahead assertions (`(?=...`).

- The combination of `\K` and `(?=...)` allows constraining the matching part of the regex to the *subexpression of interest*.
  Note that *no `grep` implementation supports capture groups*, but the above, thanks to the features enabled by `-P`, is an emulation of extracting a *single* capture-group value.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `-m1` limits the number of matching *lines* to 1, but with `-o` also present, *multiple* matches *on that 1 line* are still *all* printed.

  - Additionally, while you can use `(...)` for *precedence*, that doesn't constitute a *capture group* in `grep`, because there's *no support for extracting capture-group values in `grep`*.
- Even with `-E` for *extended* regex support, advanced constructs such as non-greedy matching (`.*?`) are *not* supported.